# How to tell what action was taken by the JPA save method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a repo:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository<SomeClass, Long> {
    SomeClass findById(Long id);
}
```

and I need to save objects to it:

```
SomeClass someClass = GetAMaybeNewSomeClass();
someClass = someRepository.save(someClass);
```

how do I tell, in code, what operation the save call did? I need to know if someClass already existed in the database, and if it did exist, I need to know if the call to save actually changed it.

I could do this by calling findById before the save operation and comparing what I find with what I'm saving, but I'd rather use something built in to the framework if it exists.

Comment: Would entity listeners solve your problem? Other than that, I can't think of any built-in mechanism that could help here

Comment: I think that you need a audit framework. Hibernate Envers do this http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save` operation in Spring combine the `persist` and the `merge` methods, the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/5ec2d41c446f0b6855b141af405e5f8552b5c539/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L481-L494) of that method is:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

So, know exactly what operation the framework does when you call the `save` method I think is not possible, so If you do need to know, you should use persist and merge methods directly from JPA or create your own methods.

**UPDATE:**

You can also use [existsById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#existsById-ID-) method from CrudRepository

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MappedSuperClass base entity that contains a method that returns a flag based on whether the entity is new or not, following a pattern shown in the Spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites.strategies).